# Is the possibility of a science of complexity a question of philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I would like to delve into an interesting query? Is the number of sciences possible predefined? And more specifically-have we already discovered all the "major" sciences so we don't have room for any more?

How about complexity? Sure we see a lot of complex things around us, so, why don't we invent a new science about them? Or is it better to "stick to the old" because it had worked so well in the past? I would like to explore the question "Can there be a new science for things we everyday see constantly with all of our senses but don't know what forces shape them?" Like currents, patterns, social change, Life? All they have the same property we can well recognize-they are **complex** but does it imply the need of a new science or is it better to "leave them be as they are" and shut the door for any new field of exploration because we have enough old sciences and there is really no room for anything new?

I would just like to reflect on the question has science became biased by now because there are "enough"(according to the **subjective** criteria of some researchers)sciences already and we don't "need" new ones even if there are phenomena which became accessible only after the development of other sciences and can just now begin to be uncovered for our knowledge(I envision here the behaviour of complex systems)? Or is it better to follow the "piece by piece" approach and regard each science by its own field of investigation adopting the view that cross-referencing the sciences and searching for a common phenomenon amongst them is causa perduta?

I wonder which approach a philosophically inclined scientist should take?

P.S.Thank you for your replies in advance.

Comment: The science of complexity is already invented, see [Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity). New sciences bubble up all the time by splitting off from more general established ones, and by interdisciplinary mixing, [data science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science) is a recent addition. The demarcation questions you are asking are mostly pragmatic questions for scientists themselves to handle, the answers are highly context dependent. Some methodology of science issues may arise but your question is so broad it is hard to tell which ones specifically.

Comment: See how many different "possible sciences" are listed in your Wikipedia entry. Are you sure it is invented? If it is why are there so many different paths and yet no common ground among them?

Comment: All sciences have multiple subdisciplines, presumably "the" science of complexity will incorporate all those dealing with complexity. But could you be make the question more specific? Is it about something like the [Unity of Science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-unity)? Or perhaps the view on the subject of some particular philosopher or school? I am afraid, this question might be closed as too broad or unclear like the one before. It may seem counter-intuitive but SE is not designed for reflections, discussions or exchange of personal opinions on open-ended topics.

Comment: Basically, I want to know do philosophers seriously regard the possibility of the existence of science able to define the term complexity in a broader range-e.g. go out of the concept of a particular science and concentrate on traits systems in many different fields can have, center itself on a single tenet(this is what I mean when I ask you about many different "possible sciences"-if it is the true science of complexity there will be only one central tenet able to link all the rest in a single paradigm)and yet have the means to be readily experimentally verifiable? Am I now clearer?

Comment: Now, how about those 3 points? Are they enough for a new science?

Comment: Are you unhappy with the links on Wiki's disambiguation page for complexity theory? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_theory

Comment: How a branch of science is defined is simply a taxonomic classification making it easier for us to understand what particular persons or person are trying to understand in nature. Nature does not recognize the classifications...there is nothing new to nature...

Comment: @user4894, what I am not happy about isn't Wikipedia. I just think It is an expression of the scientific consensus at this point in time. I can't control what all scientists think, so there is no reason to feel happy or unhappy about it. Wasting emotions on this is like wasting emotions on the weather. You can't control it-so stop worrying! This is my attitude. I just want to see can the community reach to a **single** science of complexity combining the views of all the sciences or is it causa perduta?

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda ,the problem isn't taxonomy here. It is the question can we even have such a science at all. The question is: Is there **single unifying principle** behind all complex behaviour in nature which can serve as the foundation of a new science?" This is the question I am trying to ask here.

Comment: @YordanYordanov I didn't ask about Wiki. I asked about the links. Compexity theory, algorithmic information theory, chaos theory. Also general systems theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_theory Why are those so unsatisfactory to you that when pointed to them you don't even see them?

Comment: @user4894, please, see my previous comment-I told you **where** is that **single unifying principle** which can constitute a new science? Yes, there are complex phenomena throughout the world(not just the living one)but what is this **universal principal underlying them**? I don't know how many time I have to bold it to make it clearer? The example you give all show **different** methods of investigating complexity all having in essence **different underlying principles**, As far as I can say everybody knows what is complexity, but no one knows what is **the reason it exists**?

Comment: This **reason** is the foundation of the new science in my mind and if we can find there is a unifying principle behind it and design experiments to confirm the conclusions we have made-well, that is the start of a **new science**. All you cite are different **methods** at looking at complexity, not **a unifying principle** behind it, let alone possible experimental designs to confirm them. Only information theory in thermodynamics "touches" on experiments but all the other are just different proposals on a drawing board. Then where is that **universal principle underlying them**?

Comment: "I don't know how many time I have to bold it to make it clearer?" -- It is ambiguous whether you're looking for a single principle, or a new science. Your question is unclear. Do you want a science or a principle? What is the "single principle" behind physics? The single principle behind math? "As far as I can say everybody knows what is complexity, but no one knows what is the reason it exists?" We all know that the universe exists but nobody knows the reason. Do you believe in reasons? That seems like a theological concern.

Comment: Physics is easy-mathematically expressible experimentally verifiable natural **laws**! :) Here is your **reason** for physics and I am pretty sure this is a point even a layman can understand. You don't need special education to understand what is the reason for a science to explore the laws of Nature? In this question I am wondering can we do the same about complexity?

Comment: I am not sure I see a "single unifying principle" even in physics, the ones behind general relativity and quantum theory are incompatible with each other, which is why people are after the string theory. Certainly, psychology and sociology have no unifying principles less vague than complexity, so it is not a requirement for a science. But at present the notion of Kolmogorov complexity/algorithmic information seems to be somewhat central to the topic, and e.g. [Chaitin speculates about applying it to biology](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~chaitin/mex.html).

Comment: The comments on this question make it seem like a classic case of someone posting a question with an answer already in their minds and then not being receptive to any suggestions that don't validate the presupposed position. Complexity is a well defined field of study already, examples have been given ad nauseam above. It seems like you care much more about debating your point than getting an answer to your question.

Comment: I mean something else important here @Conifold-that unlike physics people can **disagree** that there is even such thing as complexity because there can be different **definitions** of what the field of complexity is and therefore the question can dissolve in philosophy as its objects of investigation disappear because they can be though of as pertaining to different fields of investigation, respectively in different sciences. If that happens, will there be the need for a science of complexity? Not_Here how is what I have in mind as an answer related to the question: Should I ask it?

Comment: I edited the question a little bit. How is it now? Do you suggest any more edits?

Answer (score 1):

The number and organization of the sciences is not-predetermined, and in fact it constantly changes as the sciences evolve and scientists find new reasons to collaborate across disciplines.

Two prominent examples of new sciences from the recent past include:

- Environmental science, an amalgam of certain subfields of other sciences that has become a subject in its own right over the last few decades.
- Computer science, which arguably branched off from a combination of mathematics and electrical engineering (though it's not clear that either mathematics or electrical engineering are sciences).

Many other smaller interdisciplinary fields of science exist, and new ones are being created all the time as researchers find new connections between different disciplines. The field of complexity that you are looking for resembles [systems science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_science), though I'm not sure it's quite what you have in mind.

For the most part, these new sciences are created organically as researchers on the ground find new and fruitful ways to collaborate.  Sciences that seem relevant and produce interesting results grow over time, while sciences that run out of ideas or things to investigate disappear.

But I also think you overestimate the importance of subdivision of science into fields.  Individual scientists do not always feel bound to specific fields, and there are a large number of researchers who investigate connections between different fields and collaborate outside their discipline.  You're perceiving science as a centrally planned activity with some sort of hierarchical organization, but in fact scientists more closely resemble a  [swarm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence) of individual actors moving from place to place and searching everywhere they can for significant scientific results.  Indeed, formal interdisciplinary fields usually arise because there are *already scientists working on them*, not the other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately, your point of view depends too much on political situation in the respective country. In some countries(may be where you are)science may be a free-of-limits activity, but in others science is part of a very well organized institutes which get their grants and proposals on the basis of the results their respective field can propose to achieve. It is true some people can consider science to lack a general "division" by Nature and anybody can explore anything and turn it into a science but this isn't always the case in academic institutions. This is why division is important,

Comment: Well, grants and organization exist everywhere, and it's true that these can be forces that push science into a sort of rigid structure.  At the same time, there is also a lot of incentive for researchers to go off the beaten path, since you're more likely to discover something significant if you're not investigating the same thing as everyone else. I think my essential point remains that new fields of science are created all the time, usually by small groups of researchers who discover something new worth investigating.

Comment: Why not then universal principle behind complexity be one such [citation]something new worth investigating[citation]? :)

Comment: @YordanYordanov Oh this is a about the search for grants and not the search for truth! You are making a political point, not a technical one. This is much more clear now. You mean why is the scientific establishment in your country the way it is. I don't know. Human nature, probably.

Comment: My country is a country like any other country-there are good things about our science and there are bad things about it. But one good thing is we have quite good standards as to what is science and what isn't. The moment you can provide **mechanism** to explain your findings you **can** start a science. If however you have no idea what is **the reason** behind the phenomena you are investigating you can't claim this is a science. How about that criterion?

Comment: And, by the way, how much money I can get if I propose a new science of complexity is **not** the topic here, so why don't we stay on the topic is there a place for a science of complexity under the sun?

Comment: "The moment you can provide mechanism to explain your findings you can start a science. If however you have no idea what is the reason behind the phenomena you are investigating you can't claim this is a science." -- Totally rejected by Newton. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotheses_non_fingo Newton understood that science is descriptive and not explanatory. He didn't have a reason for gravity, no cause, no mechanism, no explanation. He took criticism for that. But he well knew that all he had was a mathematical description of how gravity behaves. That's all. No reason.

Comment: Did you even read my last comment @user4894 ?(Sorry if you take it personally, I don't want to be rude) I told you there if there were no laws of nature to be discovered, there would be no physics. If apples sometimes flew in the air and sometimes fall to the ground there would be nothing to discover. I think this is a viable point of my question-actually may be it is the point of the question-if we can **define** a world without complexity-by let's say assigning different names(e.g through semantics)to objects pertaining to different fields of science one can reasonably well argue there is NO

Comment: SUCH THING AS COMPLEXITY. Then the question is there any possibility of a science of complexity becomes quite the philosophical one I think. If philosophy can deny a science by "manipulating definitions" do you think there is **any real basis for this science** at all?

Comment: I **personally**(I am just expressing my PERSONAL opinion here, so it isn't any point of view I can 100% protect with scientific arguments but is just **belief** like any hypothesis is :)**believe** if one can deny an entire science by just "manipulating words", than the real world foundation of that science is quite(for the lack of a better word)shaky! All I want to pay your attention here is the possibility the science of complexity is real precisely because it **can't** be just "denied by definition". Which if true means there are some real mechanisms generating complexity here!

Answer (score 1):

To declare interest, first of all, I studied chemistry as an undergraduate, then computing and I am currently a philosophy undergraduate in London.

So, I feel that there is something of a hierarchy, with maths, physics, chemistry always supporting the newer fields. I don't have a reductionist view, in that I feel, for example, that biochemistry has [emergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) features which are a product of [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_system). However, if I had a reductionist view, I would probably put the biochemists in with the chemists, so, for me, it is somewhat a matter of philosophy.

A great deal of base computer science is maths and logic, but when looking at networks with many computers and lots of messages, complexity reappears. Also, expressing logic efficiently as circuits combines physics, programming (Verilog, for example) topology and other pieces of maths, so as @jim-belk above says, collaborations and connections appear.

Lastly, it's worth looking at the Santa Fe Institute, their research projects are based on the belief that complexity **is** a scientific subject.